# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost/sakila

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to set up JDBC but I'm getting this error.

I tried adding the dependency in pom.xml and even jar file nothing works. I tried the methods mentioned in previous questions, nothing works.

```
public class FilmLength {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException  {
    Connection dbCon = null;
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/sakila";
    String username = "devuser";
    String password = "Demo@123";
    String query = "select * from film ";


    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        st = dbCon.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            String title = rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println(title);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        dbCon.close();
        st.close();
        rs.close();
    }



}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 
`String url = "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/sakila";`

it should be
`String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila";`

Comment: Instead of answering, you should point out typos in a comment and vote/flag to close as such.